# Can backend data overwrite maxLength for inputField

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, dom

I am new to React and whole understanding of Front end development. So excuse me if its a silly question.

I have this below html input and its maxLength is specified as 24. So it will only allow user to enter upto 24 characters. If user tries tying anything more, it wont allow and only 24 characters are seen.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="24" id="sessionNo" name="sessionNum" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />
```

Uptil now is ok. But the earlier code had maxLength="32". So users had saved upto 32 characters and that data is stored in Db. When this default value is picked and shown in input field, what will i be seeing ? Will i see truncated 24 characters only or will i see 32 characters initially and as user edits the field, it will truncate additional characters and only 24 characters will be shown. "

Any suggestions highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might depend on the browser, but my local test with chrome says the following: values longer than the max are shown if set programmatically (setting the value of the element), but it is not possible to add characters to the input field. They can only be removed.

This might be different for other browsers.

Thanks to @thespeciamone for the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/nukeboy212/9oabqgxu/)

```
<input style = "width: 500px" maxlength = "24" value = "More Than Twenty Four Characters Boi. Also users can inspect element and delete the maxlength setting and now there is no limit.">
```

Comment: A little jsfiddle test: https://jsfiddle.net/nukeboy212/9oabqgxu/

Comment: Thanks Benjamin and @thespeciamone- this jsfiddle helped me understand well..